# run java app on server

Tags: java, web-applications

my host (one.com) doesn´t support java webapps. But I have a java programm that fetches new data from the twitter API and stores the data in some text files. I use those textfiles to display info graphics based on the data in my website project with processing (java based data-vis language). running processing sketches on the server is no problem, but the support told me that running a java webapp is not supported.

What I want to do is run the java program that fetches the new data in the background. It should update the textfiles regularly, maybe once every 24h. How what I go about doing that? If the server doesn´t supprort java webapps, what is the next best thing I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look at the host site tells me they host PHP applications and allows you to run cron jobs that you set up through the control panel on the site. You can write your program in PHP, which should be simple to do, and then create a cron job that invokes your PHP program each day at the desired time. Is there some specific requirement that requires Java? From your desciption of the problem this is not clear.

Comment: no, there is not. I was thinking also that this is probably the best solution (not counting switching web host services). thanks for the quick reply :)